# How to access a keyboard via Bluetooth in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard, bluetooth

I want to access a keyboard via Bluetooth.

For example :
Two devices connect each other via Bluetooth if I open keyboard in the first device, and I want access that keyboard in another device in any edittext.

So how can I access that keyboard in another device via bluetooth in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect a EditText keyboard popping up :

```
Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int proposedheight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    final int actualHeight = getHeight();

    if (actualHeight > proposedheight){
        // Keyboard is shown
    } else {
        // Keyboard is hidden
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

---

To capture a key event

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 

         // keycode should be sent over bluetooth. 

          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

To inject keypresses in your Activity simply call `onKeyDown()` with the appropriate KeyEvent

---

To open up a keyboard

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
// only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

and close it :

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

If you are not interested in popping up the keyboard on the other phone, simply ignore this section. Use the good old : `setText()`

---

Now how you form the chatting protocol by which Bluetooth sends these key events is up to you.Hint:  [RemoteDroid used OscMessages](http://code.google.com/p/remotedroid/source/browse/#svn/trunk/RemoteDroid2.0/src/com/illposed/osc%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Comment: @Reno..but i am not using edittext...i want to access 1st device keyboard to any editor (Edittext) of another device...So how i can get that keys in edittext for example : if i want enter username and password in another device then i can access 1st device keyboard ?

Comment: What you you talking about ... you're not using EditText's yet you want to use EditText? I can't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to have someone on Phone A press a key and the key be entered into the currently highlighted field on Phone B then this is what you need:

The app on both phones (One in "Send Mode" and one in "Receive Mode").

You need to capture the key press as coded in @Reno 's answer. You then need to use the transport mechanism (in this case Bluetooth) to transfer it to the other device. You should be able to search for more than enough tutorials on transferring strings via bluetooth.

You need the app on phone B to receive the string/character and then output it to the currently selected field. This means finding the focused field (Again, answers out there on SO) and then writing to that field (Which will likely be `setText("A");`).